# Do Incomplete Normed Vector Spaces Whose Duals Are Reflexive Exist?

Tags: functional-analysis

It is clear to me that if $X$ is a Banach space and its dual $X^*$ is reflexive, then $X$ is also reflexive (that is, the natural map between $X$ and its double dual $X^{**}$ is a surjective isometric isomorphism). However, I suspect that the conclusion fails to be true if we remove the completeness hypothesis, but I can't formalize this argument.

Are there famous examples of incomplete (and hence non-reflexive) normed vector spaces whose duals are still reflexive? Or does the reflexivity of $X^*$ imply that $X$ is reflexive (and hence Banach) even if without assuming *ab initio* that $X$ is a Banach space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y$ be any reflexive Banach space (or even a Hilbert space), and let $X$ be a proper dense subspace of $Y$.  Then $X$ is not complete and its completion is $Y$.  We then have $X^* = Y^*$ which is reflexive.

Comment: Thank you very much. To establish the desired example based on your hints, I took $$Y\equiv\left\{(c_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\mathbb C\,\bigg|\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|c_n|^2<+\infty\right\}$$ with the norm $(c_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\mapsto\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|c_n|^2}$ and $$X\equiv\left\{(c_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\,\big|\,\exists N\in\mathbb Z_+:c_n=0\,\forall n>N\right\}.$$ Then $Y$ is an infinite-dimensional reflexive normed vector space, $X$ is a proper dense infinite-dimensional incomplete subspace. Moreover, $X^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $Y^*$ and $Y^*$ is reflexive, and thus so is $X^*$.