# The weak and weak$^*$ topologies of the dual of a reflexive Banach space coincide

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, weak-topology

Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a normed vector space. Let $E^*, E^{**}$ be the dual and bidual of $E$ respectively. Let $\tau := \sigma(E^*, E^{**})$ and $\tau' := \sigma(E^{*}, E)$ be the weak and weak$^*$ topologies of $E^*$ respectively. If $E \cong E^{**}$, i.e., $E$ is isometrically isomorphic to $E^{**}$, then $\tau = \tau'$. This would be the case if $E$ is a reflexive Banach space or a Hilbert space in particular.

Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: I think that the weak and weak star topologies coincide if and only if $E$ is reflexive, which (the latter) is not always the case when $E$ is isometrically isomorphic to $E^{**}$

Comment: @EvangelopoulosPhoevos You are right! I have found a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651556/is-reflexivity-necessary-for-the-weak-and-weak-topologies-to-coincide?rq=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflexivity is the isomorphism of $E$ with $E^{**}$ via the specific map $x\longmapsto \hat x$, where $\hat x(\varphi)=\varphi(x)$. It is not enough for reflexivity to have $E\simeq E^{**}$ isometrically. This was established by R.C. James in [PNAS 37 (1950), 174-178](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063327/pdf/pnas01564-0044.pdf).